# Scala Play No implicit format for Seq[Option[models.ProcessStepTemplatesModel]] available

Tags: scala, playframework

I have scala Play application where I want to do something like this:

```
implicit val ProcessStepsFormat: OFormat[ProcessSteps] = Json.format[ProcessSteps]

case class ProcessSteps(stepsData: Seq[Option[ProcessStepTemplatesModel]])
```

Problem Is that I got this error:

```
No implicit format for Seq[Option[models.ProcessStepTemplatesModel]] available.
```

How can I change the format that It will work?

thanks at all

UPDATE

```
case class ProcessStepTemplatesModel(
                                      id: Option[Int],
                                      title: String,
                                      createdat: String,
                                      updatedat: String,
                                      deadline: Option[Date],
                                      comment: Option[String],
                                      stepType: Int,
                                      deleted: Boolean,
                                      processtemplate: Option[Int],
                                      derivedProcesses: Seq[ProcessStepTemplatesDerivedProcessesModel],
                                      prerequisites: Seq[ProcessStepPrerequisitesModel],
                                      postconditions: Seq[ProcessStepPostconditionModel],
                                      addProcessToProcessStepArray: Seq[ProcessStepsTemplates_ProcessTemplatesModel])

object ProcessStepTemplatesModel {
  implicit val processStepFormat = Json.format[ProcessStepTemplatesModel]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you declare an implicit format for `ProcessStepTemplatesModel` ?

Comment: why do I need one for the Model as well and how should it look like?

added the model above

Comment: You need to declare at least one Format[X] per class you declare, before being able to serialize your collection. Each time PlayJson is confronted to an unknown type (i.e  a type that is not a basic type like String, Long, Date, etc.), it will search for an implicit Format to serialize/deserialize it. You can also just pass a Reads[X] or a Writes[X] depending on what you try to do.

In your example, it will ask you an implicit format for : ProcessStepTemplatesDerivedProcessesModel, ProcessStepPrerequisitesModel, ProcessStepPostconditionModel, 
ProcessStepsTemplates_ProcessTemplatesModel